# what happens in scala when loading objects that extends App?

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I've encountered a somewhat bizzar behavior in objects that extends `App`. take a look at the following REPL commands:

```
scala> object A extends App {val x = "I am null"}
defined module A

scala> object B {val x = "I am a string"}
defined module B

scala> A.x
res0: java.lang.String = null

scala> B.x
res1: java.lang.String = I am a string
```

well, this is a bit weird... but it gets weirder. i then thought the vals in an `object` go into some lazy evaluation... so i tried a real `lazy val`:

```
scala> object C extends App {lazy val x = "What am I?"}
defined module C

scala> C.x
res2: java.lang.String = What am I?
```

so what's happening here? why is a regular val gets a null value?
why does this behavior changes when i use `lazy val`?
 and what is so special with the `App` trait, that makes the regular vals to be unevaluated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

App extends [DelayedInit](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/DelayedInit.html) trait. So *all statements and all value definitions* are moved to `delayedInit` method. Lazy val works because it compiles to method.

For example if you decompile this class:

```
class TestApp extends App{
  val test = "I am null"
  lazy val testLazy ="I am a string"
}
```

You will get class with 'lazy method':

```
public String testLazy()
{
    if((bitmap$0 & 1) == 0)
        synchronized(this)
        {
            if((bitmap$0 & 1) == 0)
            {
                testLazy = "I am a string";
                bitmap$0 = bitmap$0 | 1;
            }
            BoxedUnit _tmp = BoxedUnit.UNIT;
        }
    return testLazy;
}
```

and delayedInit method in inner class `delayedInit.body`:

```
 public final class delayedInit.body extends AbstractFunction0
        implements ScalaObject
    {

        public final Object apply()
        {
            $outer.test_$eq("I am null");
            return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
        }

        private final TestApp $outer;
....
```

So value "I am null" will be assigned to `test` field only when delayedInit is called.